# ignore project.pbxproj changes related to developer certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a team of developers, each one with their own `developer account`.

The problem comes with development certificates. Due to each one having its own certificate generated, the `project.pbxproj` file is changing every time any developer merge their changes with the main branch (i.e, master & their working branches).

Attending to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html) documentation, every developer has their own certificate and it's logical that the `project.pbxproj` changes. Is there any possibility to ignore these changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think xcconfig file usage would help you to omit constant conflicts in git. Idea is that you put certain build settings from *project.pbxproj* to *xcconfig* file. I suspect that in your case that variable build setting will be **DEVELOPMENT_TEAM**. To add xcconfig file to your project go to Xcode -> File -> New... -> File:

[image]

Let's assume I've named it Config.xcconfig. Next step is to use that file in project settings. To do this go to **Configurations** section of your project:

[image]

After that you'll have to add new key to `Config.xcconfig`. Example:
`DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = #YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM#`, **DEVELOPMENT_TEAM** value can be retrieved from your *project.pbxproj* file:

[image]

After moving **DEVELOPMENT_TEAM** key from `project.pbxproj` to `Config.xcconfig` it can be removed from Project settings. `Config.xcconfig` then should be added to git but it's value should be modified only locally by any engineer from your team.

In the same manner keys like `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER`, `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` can be moved.

More information on build settings and xcconfig files can be found [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html) and [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html).